# How to fix Twitter Bootstrap css missing for the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a problem with the tooltip using bootstrap.
The tooltip appears, but it's without the css. So all I see is a box with the tooltip without the css.

But if I add this line:

```
<script src="http//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

right before calling the css that calls:

```
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Then the css appears and the tooltip displays properly.
The thing is that we're using version 3.3.1 and once I change the javascript line to this version it stops working.

This is how we're configuring the js on the system:

```
// file: require-setup.js
//
// Declare this variable before loading RequireJS JavaScript library
// To config RequireJS after it’s loaded, pass the below object into require.config();

var require = {

    shim : {
        "bootstrap" : { "deps" :['jquery'] },
        'treegrid' : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "treegridBS3" : { "deps" :['treegrid'] },
        "tagsinput" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "typeahead" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "combobox" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "datepicker" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "moment" : { "deps" :['jquery'] },
        "datetimepicker" : { "deps" :['bootstrap','moment'] },
        "touchspin" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "metisMenu" : { "deps" :['bootstrap'] },
        "jquery-ui" : { "deps" :['jquery'] },
        "fancytree" : { "deps" :['jquery-ui'] },
        "datatables.net": { "deps" :['jquery'] },
        "datatables": { "deps" :['bootstrap', 'datatables.net'] },
        "jquery-browser": { "deps" :['jquery'] }
    },
    paths: {

        "jquery" : "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap" :  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min",
        "tagsinput" :  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.5.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min",
        "typeahead" :  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/3.1.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min",
        "treegridBS3"  :  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treegrid/0.2.0/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3", 
        "treegrid"  : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-treegrid/0.2.0/js/jquery.treegrid",
        "datepicker"  : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min",
        "moment" : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min",
        "datetimepicker" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min",
        "touchspin" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/3.1.1/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min",
        "metisMenu" : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.metismenu/1.1.2/js/metismenu.min",
        "jquery-ui" : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min",
        "fancytree" : "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fancytree/2.15.0/jquery.fancytree-all.min",
        "datatables.net" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
        "datatables" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min",
        "combobox" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.7/js/bootstrap-combobox.min",
        "jquery-browser" : "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.1.0/jquery.browser.min"
    }

    //"datatables" : "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
    //"datatables_bs3" : "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min"

};
//"jquery" : "../../assets/javascripts/jquery-2.1.3",
```

And that's how my html starts:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<title>Cost Centre Management</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/javascripts/require-setup.js"
    th:src="@{/assets/require-setup.js}">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/requirejs/2.1.14/require.min.js">

</script>
```

At some point on the html I have this where it should display properly the tooltip:

```
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
                                                            title="WIREFRAME FUND"
                                                            th:title="|${costCentreSearchResult.fundDescription}|"
                                                            th:text="${costCentreSearchResult.fundCode}">FUND_CODE</a>
                                                        </td>
```

Note: The line is at the end of the html. After the jquery.

Comment: can you include the relevant parts of your HTML document (links, scripts, elements that use the data-toggle attribute)?

Comment: @cwanjt - Just added more information.